# How to integrate PIVOT SQL Server query with ASP.NET at front end

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

```
USE [SAFLA]

DECLARE 
      @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
    , @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @cols = STUFF((
    SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(w.week_range)
    FROM Weekly_Attendance AS w
    FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')

SET @query = '
    SELECT stu_id, name, ' + @cols + ' 
    FROM (
        SELECT 
              stu.stu_id
            , stu.name
            , w.total_present_lec
            , w.week_range
        FROM Student_Registration AS stu 
        JOIN Weekly_Attendance w ON stu.stu_id = w.stu_id
    ) x
    PIVOT 
    (
        SUM(total_present_lec)
        FOR week_range in (' + @cols + ')
        --GROUP BY total_present_lec
    ) p'

EXECUTE (@query)
```

This is a sql query i want integrate with ASP.NET Page..

Comment: whatever your query is it will only return column and rows and not sure you want to show in chart or treeview because you have to use grouping another option is crystal reports

Comment: Can I use DatalistView or GridView or any Other Control....?

Comment: if you are using groups then its better to use crystal reports otherwise you can use whatever you want. I hope you know grouping lol

Comment: What is your question? What does "integration" mean? Are you asking how to display it on an ASP.NET page? Are you asking how execute a query from ASP.NET? Are you asking if this syntax will work?

Comment: yes... how to execute pivot query in asp.net... @sisdog